# Very difficult integral

Tags: integration

I'm looking for a solution to the following integral, where $a$ and $b$ are parameters:
$$
\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2 + a \left(2(bx)^6 - (bx)^{12}\right)}} dx
$$

Comment: It's a hyperelliptic integral of the 1st kind. Unless a miracle happens, it can't be expressed as anything familiar.

Comment: Where is this monster coming from ? I am really willing to know

Comment: @user8268. How did you find that it is an hyperelliptic integral ?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a closed-form solution.  However, if $a$ is "small" you can expand the integrand as a series in powers of $a$, and integrate term-by-term.

EDIT:

Note that $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2 + a u}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(2k)! (- au/4)^k }{(k!)^2 } (1-x^2)^{-k-1/2} $$

and that each  $\int x^j\ (1-x^2)^{k+1/2}\ dx$ can be done in closed form.

Comment: do you can explicite your response ?

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I do not understand your development of series.
I'm not a mathematician, I have just basic knowledge in mathematics so I'm not able to find the following of your reasoning.
Of physical point of view, I know which form will take the solution in function of parameter b, and the solution must  have a singularity for a certain value of parameter  b.

Comment: There are always  singularities, usually branch points, where $1 - x^2 + a (2 (bx)^6 - (bx)^{12}) = 0$.

Comment: This singularity is evident, and I think that there is one or two others singularities. The problem isn't the singularities, but is how to find the antiderivative!